# If I have a phone number in twilio (not flex) can I forward messages to twilio flex without porting the number over to different project?

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

It appears that in order for twilio flex agents to receive text messages using the twilio flex UI, the phone number must be within the twilio flex project.

However, I have a phone number that is configured in a project (Ill call this project A) that is configured with SIP Trunk. 
I would like to see if it is possible to allow the phone number to still live within Project A ( so voice calls continue to work as they do today) but allow SMS messages to be routed to the twilio flex agents.

This would allow Agents to continue answering inbound calls from the phone number configured in Project A, but also allow Agents to use twilio flex to respond to SMS messages that are sent to this phone number.

Is this possible?

Just to summarize here
I have two projects. 
Project A ( standard Twilio project, not flex)
Project B (Twilio Flex project)

I have a phone number I have purchased within Project A. I do not want to move this number into Project B since I want the inbound calls to continue to work the way they do today. In other words, I want inbound calls to this number to continue to route through SIP, but SMS messages result in SMS task in twilio flex. 
Is this possible?

This documentation

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020243334-Move-or-Transfer-a-Phone-Number-to-your-Flex-Project

gives me the impression that the number must live in either project A or project B, but not both. But I need to validate if this is true or not.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We do not support resource delegation between projects, so the number does have to live in either project A or B but not both.